# Volley - NoConnectionError, ProtocolException & exceeded content-length limit

Tags: android, android-volley, android-image, android-networking

I'm trying to upload an image to my server using Volley but I keep getting the error:

```
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ProtocolException: exceeded content-length limit of n bytes
```

Where n is the length of the imageData.

Connection is present so the NoConnectionError part of things is odd.

Below is all the relevant code:

```
public class UploadPhotoRequest extends BaseRequest<Boolean> {

public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type";
public static final String CONTENT_LENGTH = "Content-Length";
public static final String PREFIX = "--";
private String imageData;
private String fileName;

private static final String BOUNDARY = "#BOUNDARY#";

public UploadPhotoRequest(String authToken, String clientKey, int method, String url,
                          String imageData, String fileName) {
    super(authToken, clientKey, method, url);
    this.imageData = imageData;
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() {
    try {
        String appendMe = buildBodyString(PREFIX, BOUNDARY, fileName, imageData);
        return appendMe.getBytes(PROTOCOL_CHARSET);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Logger.e("UploadPhotoRequest", "Failed trying to get bytes for upload");
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + BOUNDARY;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put(CONTENT_TYPE, getBodyContentType());
    //Other server headers
    headers.put(CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(imageData.length()));
    return headers;
}

@Override
public Response<Boolean> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    if (isReqSuccessful(response)) {
        return Response.success(true, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } else {
        return Response.error(new VolleyError(ErrorMessages.UPLOAD_PHOTO));
    }
}

private String buildBodyString(String prefix, String boundary, String fileName, String image) {
    StringBuffer stringBuilder = new StringBuffer();
    stringBuilder
            .append(prefix)
            .append(boundary)
            .append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[image]\"; filename=\"")
            .append(fileName)
            .append("\"")
            .append("Content-Type: image/jpeg")
            .append(image)
            .append(prefix)
            .append(boundary)
            .append(prefix);
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

}

BaseRequest extends from Request and contains some common info & helpers used by my other requests.

The image in question is encoded like this :

```
 String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(outputStream.toByteArray(),
                            Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: `imageData.length()` may not be the actual image size. Check once again.

Comment: Have you solved it? i am also having this issue.